# How to scp a file from local to remote from within remote connection terminal

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, scp

Suppose a file called `Test` is in my `/home/myname/` on `Ubuntu`. To transfer to remote I'll open a terminal and go:

```
 scp "Test" user@node:"~/Folder1/folder2"
```

How would I alter this command to be able to transfer `Test` into `folder2` from within an `SSH` connection to `user@node`? As in, if I *first* open a `SHH` connection, then from within the terminal that's connected to remote what command do I issue to conduct the above transfer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly the following is your setup:

1. "Test" file is on your local machine
2. you ssh another machine, lets call it remote machine
3. you want to move the file to yet another machine, lets call it node

So, if remote machine have access to your local machine you can just

```
ssh you@your_local_machine:/path/to/Test user@node:~/Folder/folder2
```

this is usually the case if you are on the same network, connected to same home / office router etc.

this can't be done if remote machine can't access your local machine, that's usually the case if remote machine is a server, say on EC2 and alike, and your local machine is not publicly available, using a public ip or dynamic dns setup, but that's another story.